# How to get the first match of a pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I get just the c999752_ABC_PAT from the string below?

```
$file = q(M:\c999752_ABC_PAT\Informatica_AVOB\ABC_infa\dummy\TestDeliver.txt);
```

Comment: Obvious first - Can't you just explode by "\"?

Comment: I use this: =~ /(M\:\\.+)\\/; it gives me this:  M:\ccadm01_QRF_DEV\Informatica_QVOB\QRF_infa, but I want only c999752_ABC_PAT or M:\c999752_ABC_PAT

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^.*?\\(.*?)\\.*$
|   |   |     |->matches till the end
|   |   |->your content matched till the first occurance of \
|   |->match lazily till the first \
|->start of the text
```

`Group1` captures your data

Answer (score 1):

Or use what Eammon suggested:

```
my $firstPart = ( split /\\/, $file )[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Spec::Win32;

my $file = q(M:\c999752_ABC_PAT\Informatica_AVOB\ABC_infa\dummy\TestDeliver.txt);
my ($volume, $directories) = File::Spec::Win32->splitpath($file);
my @directories = File::Spec::Win32->splitdir($directories);

print $directories[1], "\n";
```